# Ramsey spectroscopy of atoms -- Heisenberg Picture

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, atomic-clocks

I was reading [this](http://lukin.physics.harvard.edu/wp-uploads/Papers/Theses/AxelThesis.pdf) thesis on the Ramsey spectroscopy, which deals with Ramsey spectroscopy of a two level system using the Heisenberg picture. This topic is dealt with in the Appendix A.1 of the given thesis.

I think I understand how Ramsey spectroscopy works in the Schrödinger picture ─ a $\pi/2$ pulse is given (but the $\pi/2$ is not resonant with the atomic transition frequency, hence the atom enters an improperly mixed ground and excited state). A free time evolution is done for a time $T$, and then the system is given another $\pi/2$ pulse (again, non-resonant but with the same frequency). By measuring the relative number of atoms in the excited state and ground state after the pulse-evolve-pulse sequence, we are able to calculate the number of atoms in the ground and excited states, and hence the phase difference and eventually the difference in frequency of the source and the resonant frequency of the atom ($\omega-\omega_0$).

However, in this thesis, as I mentioned earlier, the topic of Ramsey spectroscopy is dealt with in terms of the Heisenberg picture, which I find a bit confusing. They define angular momentum $J_x$, $J_y$ and $J_z$ operators based on the energy levels $|e\rangle$ and $|g\rangle$, which refer to the excited and ground state energies respectively. It is after this part that it gets confusing. I would like to mention that in this thesis, they have considered a $\pi/2$-evolve-$(-\pi/2)$ sequence instead.

They proceed to say that the $\pi/2$ pulse rotates the angular momentum vectors by $\pi/2$ about the $x$-axis, the free evolution makes the net vector rotate about the $z$-axis with an angular velocity which is $\omega-\omega_0$ and another $(-\pi/2)$ pulse.

My questions about the explanation are:

1. Isn't the $\pi/2$ pulse only approximate, and that the entire reason for the phase difference comes from the fact that it is not an exact $\pi/2$ pulse? How can they assume that the original pulse **exactly** rotates the angular momentum operators by $\pi/2$?
2. How does the time evolution of the pulse when it is propagating freely without any interaction, in the evolve phase, depend on the frequency of the probe light used ($\omega$)? Since the Hamiltonian is just the free Hamiltonian with no interaction between the levels, why does the probe light come in? Shouldn't they just evolve with a frequency $\omega_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ramsey sequence, the initial state of the atom is $|g\rangle$, so the angular momentum operators can be defined such that $\sigma_z = -1$, and $\sigma_x = \sigma_y = 0$. This is very convenient to think about in the picture of the Bloch sphere, in which the qubit state is represented by a vector along the surface of a unit sphere. A state vector pointed straight down or straight up, along the $z$ axis, corresponds to the two eigenstates of $\sigma_z$: $|g\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$, respectively. The $z$ coordinate of these points are $\pm 1$, while the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are both 0.

Along the equator are the even superpositions of $|g\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$. At the tip of the sphere with largest $x$ coordinate, the state is an eigenfunction of $\sigma_x$: $(|g\rangle \pm |e\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. At these points, one can see from the coordinates in the Bloch sphere that $\sigma_x = \pm 1$, while $\sigma_y = \sigma_z  = 0$.

The first $\pi/2$ pulse is applied at a non-resonant frequency $\omega \ne \omega_0$, but is timed to perfectly prepare an even superposition of $|g\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$. This is a point on the equator of the Bloch sphere, so we may as well define our $x$ and $y$ axes appropriately so that this point is an eigenstate of $\sigma_y$: $\sigma_y = 1$, $\sigma_x = \sigma_z = 0$.

After we turn off the laser field, the Hamiltonian is given only by the energetic splitting between $|g\rangle $ and $|e\rangle$ in the reference frame rotating at $\omega$: so $H \propto  \hbar(\omega_0 - \omega) \sigma_z$. Now, the first $\pi/2$ pulse rotated us to $\sigma_y = 1$, so the question is how does the operator $\sigma_y$ evolve under the Hamiltonian $\sigma_z$. The equations of motion of (time independent) operators are given by $\frac{d}{dt} A = i [H, A]$, so we obtain that $\dot{\sigma_y} = i [(\omega_0-\omega)\sigma_z, \sigma_y] = (\omega_0-\omega)\sigma_x$. At the same time, we can find the equation of motion for $\sigma_x$: $\dot{\sigma_x} = i[(\omega_0-\omega)\sigma_z, \sigma_x] = -(\omega_0-\omega)\sigma_y$. These coupled equations can be reformulated to show that each $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ undergo simple harmonic motion with frequency $\omega_0 - \omega$.

Now we see that in the Heisenberg picture, the precession around the $z$ axis is given by oscillatory motion of the $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ operators - and if we look carefully we'll see that these operators oscillate out of phase, corresponding to the circular motion along the equator of the Bloch sphere, all at the rate set by the difference in frequency between the natural level splitting and the laser pulse frequency.